bash: <path>/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.8.1/python_files/deactivate/bash/deactivate: Permission denied
I am new to python on a freshly installed windows OS. I am running a venv in ubuntu linux and followed a guide to activate the venv. Everything was going smoothly until I tried to 'deactivate' the venv. I am getting this bash error when I try to deactivate the venv.
Not sure if this helps or not, but here is the system setup:

VS code in windows using bash
Remote SSH (v0.112.0)
WSL (v0.88.2)
Python is installed and executed in ubuntu (v2024.8.1)

Any help is appreciated :) Have a good day!
I tried using deactivate to exit the python venv. I expected the (venv) to go away in terminal.
I tried cd'ing to scripts folder and other folders and running deactivate. Also sudo deactivate. I googled the error and nothing popped up on google. Some articles talk about executing an admin powershell however I am not sure how that applies to me since this is in linux. Maybe vs-code needs admin rights? I looked at the activate script in the venv folder, looked thru the deactivate command code, and do not see the error message I am getting.
EDIT:
It went away when I created another VS-code window :) Yaaay!

I had the same issue, and I fixed it by changing the default Python interpreter for in my project. To do so press Ctrl+Shift+P and type Python: Select Interpreter. Chose one of the OS versions of Python.

You should not switch to another Python interpreter. The problem is sourced from the Microsoft Python extension. They corrected it on the pre-release version of the extension. You can switch to it from the extension manager tab.
Or, simply wait for the update ;)
